# 3D complex spatial types in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, 3d, sql-server-2019

Does SQL Server 2019 support complex spatial 3D data types in 2021, or is this planned?

Or how would you store 3D data in SQL Server right now? I found just an option to story it as 3D Points in Geometry type - so it stores just point-cloud. But to store some more complex 3D objects I am not able to find a proper way.

The PostgreSQL/PostGIS supports **Polyhedral** but this type seems to be unsupported in SQL Server. Is there similar data type in SQL Server?